# setup an IVR with Asterisk

Tags: installation, voip, asterisk, ivr

I need to setup a simple IVR system for a friend's company that will let the caller navigate through the menu by pressing phone keys. Its kind of like a bus schedule.

> for today's schedule press '1', for tomorrow's schedule press '2' and
>   so on.

It is solely an information system, i.e. no navigation route will end up with a real person but only audio messages will be played.

Now, I've never setup anything like this before and did a little digging on Google. Seems like I will be able to achieve this using Asterisk.

- What else do I need hardware-wise?
- Is a simple Linux server and a VOIP account with a provider in Germany sufficient?
- Will a VPS handle the task?
- How about multiple concurrent incoming calls?
- Are those handled by Asterisk?

Comment: Is there a programming angle?

Comment: I don't know yet...for now it's just technology related. But people seem to be eager to help and give answers...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's perfectly possible.

What you need to know:

1. Asterisk has some problems with `H323`. If your provider supplies `SIP`, ask them for `SIP` instead.
2. You may build a whole `IVR` on dial plans in your `extensions.conf`, but for complex tasks it's better to use `AGI`. These are `Perl` or `Python` or whatever language scripts that implement your `IVR` logic. Each `AGI` session spans a child process, use `FastAGI` and a network daemon if you expect frequent connections.
3. Multiple concurrent calls are not a problem, my installation of Asterisk on a simple PC handles *hundreds* sumultaneous calls.
4. The only things that may **really** affect performance are **sound conversion** and **tone detection**.

   To improve performance, you should:

   1. Stick to one codec (`µLaw` is that I use), force all `SIP` connections to use that codec, and preconvert all your sound files to it using `sox -t ul`. As soon as you've done it, all Asterisk operation amounts to reading the file bytes from disk and sending them over network with just basic wrapping. There are no math, nothing except simple read-wrap-send operations.
   2. Ask your provider to detect tones on his side and send them to you **out of band**, using `RFC 2833`. Tone detection is quite a CPU consuming operation, let them do it theirselves.

   I personally run Asterisk on a `2,66 MHz Celeron IV` with `2048 MB RAM`, under `Fedora 10 X86_64`. 150 connections at once work OK, there are no delays.

   Overall traffic amounts to about `9.6 KByte/sec` per connection. For a modern VPS there should be no problem at all.

Comment: do you think an IVR may also be realized employing a regular VPS that has Asterisk installed? Or should I rather get a dedicated server?

Comment: and can you suggest some hardware (board) for such a system?

Comment: @sepehr: man, it's been seven years! I think almost anything that can run Linux and has a network port would do, the tasks Asterisk deals with are not CPU or IO intensive at all.

Comment: @Quassnoi ,now I'm sure you have at least seven years of experience :)

Answer (score 2):

Asterisk rocks.  For a few lines a simple P3 or better will do.  Don't virtualise the PBX; Asterisk relies on pretty accurate timing.

[FreePBX](http://www.freepbx.org) makes it really easy to set up an IVR - got a decent web-based front end and supports some cool Asterisk tools out of the box.

EDIT: FreePBX isn't Asterisk - it is a pretty interface that generates the configs for you.  Trixbox includes it by default if you want a simple point and shoot solution.

If your VoIP account supports multiple incoming lines then Asterisk will use them just fine.  You also need sufficient Internet bandwidth and decent QoS.  For more than one line on a business system I would insist on a dedicated connection so you don't experience dropouts when users are accessing the net.

Comment: do you think an IVR may also be realized employing a regular VPS that has Asterisk installed? Or should I rather get a dedicated server?

Comment: If you have Asterisk installed somewhere then by all means use it.  An IVR for a handful of lines will hardly require many resources.  If you're talking a lot of lines (20+) then think about dedicated hardware.

Comment: the hyperlink to FreePBX is pointing to Free-B-P-X. The poster might want to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to build an IVR applications is to use VoiceXML designed by W3C.org (http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/) . Asterisk does not come with VoiceXML browser but there are companies that provide that for Asterisk such as SoftSyl Technologies (http://www.softsyl.com).

Companies like Cisco and Avaya also provide VoiceXML browser but they are not for Asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

If you're completely fresh, I would suggest studying FreeSWITCH instead of Asterisk. It's much better structured, and also comes with some pre-built examples, including an IVR menu, and the IVR syntax is pretty simple:   http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/IVR_Menu

I'm running a FreeSWITCH instance on a Xen virtual server, and it runs perfectly with multiple simultaneous calls.

Comment: BTW, here at the bottom is detailed description of what I've implemented: http://txlab.wordpress.com/tag/dvop-net/

Answer (score 1):

For more complex IVR's you can try [Astive Toolkit](http://astivetoolkit.org),  especially if you need databases or webservices iteration.

Answer (score 1):

IVR design in Asterisk is not difficult, but there is a bit of a "learning cliff" associated with getting your first Asterisk server up and running.

As stated by someone else, call quality is everything.  Pay to have professional grade recordings done for your IVR prompts and your announcements.  Ensure that you're using 64k codes such as uLaw and aLaw;  GSM (cellphone) might be cheap on bandwith, but it breaks your customer expectations about quality.

I strongly suggest that you put the IVR into it's own dial plan context and then direct calls into it.  That makes managing things like menu choices much easier.  For each sub-set of options, use a different dial plan context.

Try and keep your menu "shallow".  If it takes more than three menu options to get the information your customer is looking for, they are very likely to hang up, or just press "0" to talk to a human.  That defeats the point of your IVR.

If you are going to do something fairly cool with database look-ups, or account authentication or the like, I'd recommend using an "AGI" - Asterisk Gateway Interface - application.  My personal favorite is "[Adhearsion](http://adhearsion.com/)", which blends well with Ruby/Rails on the DB/Web side.

If you need help or more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with IVR in the past but mainly with large systems and have never used Asterisk. I took a quick look at their website (http://www.asterisk.org/) though and it seems very informative, have you checked there?

Comment: yepp. Already did that. But I'd like to hear from somebody that has already done what I want to do and who can tell me about possible complications or recommend on the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Its not programing related but...

Take a look at [trixbox.org](http://trixbox.org/), It supports configuration from cisco to... snom phones
Its Asterisk/Freepbx mod and everything under a nice ui!

i have a provider in australia added them as a gsm trunk, took 3hrs to setup 4phones. IVR is supported

The only problems would possibly being... voice quality of recording

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple. I'm using sipgate.de as provider for my asterisk.
you need to setup a dialplan.

this is also quite simple. take a look [here](http://www.voip-info.org/tiki-index.php?page=Asterisk%20config%20extensions.conf).
you sould also take a look into the extensions.conf.
there a some samples inside. 
the is also a sample which fits on your problem.
to connect to sipgate, take a look into their knowlogebase.
there are some samples for asterisk configuration.

sipgate is free, except you are doing outgoing calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the dial plan...

```
[menu-main]
exten => s,1,Noop()
exten => s,n(msg),Background(ForTodayPress1TomorrPress2)
exten => s,1,Goto(menu-today)
exten => s,2,Goto(menu-tomorrow)
exten => i,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => i,n,Goto(msg)
exten => t,1,Goto(msg)

[menu-today]
etc...

[menu-tomorrow]
etc...
```

Or as someone else has suggested you can do it in any language that can write to stdin and read from stdout. The phpagi implementation is my particular favorite flavor. It might fit in to this example like so where the PHP is being run on a separate box so it does not effect the PBX under any kind of load.

```
[menu-main]
exten => s,1,Noop()
exten => s,n(msg),Background(ForTodayPress1TomorrPress2)
exten => s,1,Goto(menu-today,s,1)
exten => s,2,Goto(menu-tomorrow,s,1)
exten => i,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => i,n,Goto(msg)
exten => t,1,Goto(msg)

[menu-today]
exten => s,1,Noop()
exten => s,n,agi(http://myapache/agi/readschedule.php)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup an Asterisk IVR, you can also use some Drag and Drop web based tool in order to make simple auto-attendant (like in your example) or complex IVR (managing scripting or data base driven IVR).
One option is **Cally Square**. Have a look here:
http://www.callysquare.com/