# IVR setup in PSTN

Tags: phone-number, ivr

I am trying to build a IVR system, where the IVR will receive the dial tones from user and reads messages from the database based on the dial tones. I am fairly new in this kind of matter and i have researched about solutions like asterisk but i would like to have detailed information on how to setup this system. I have the simple PSTN RJ-11 line in my office and the customer would dial the number of this line to get connected with the IVR system.

1. What are the hardware required and how will they be connected?
2. Is it possible to accept multiple calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accept multiple incoming calls in parallel you need either multiple individual lines from your service provider or a 'trunk' connection (either traditional digital trunk or an IP based SIP trunk).

There are quite a few good detailed Asterix IVR guides - some links from an answer to a similar question are:

- http://www.asterisk.org/get-started/applications/ivr
- http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/administration-guide/creating-an-ivr
- [setup an IVR with Asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495271/setup-an-ivr-with-asterisk)

On the hardware side, it depends what connection you end up getting from your service provider, but you will need some sort of line card to terminate the telephony if it is traditional analogue or digital. See this Asterix page for more information:

- http://www.asterisk.org/products/telephony-interface-cards

Note that your service provider (or an alternative provider in your area) may be able to provide you SIP / IP based 'trunks' in which case you would not need this extra hardware. It might be worth checking this out depending on your specific requirements and the price etc.