# Can i make something like multiple instances of a sip user client

Tags: sip

I am a newbie to sip protocol and very curious about it.
My basic question is:
can we create a sip user agent which can be started as multiple instances.
In layman language:
suppose if i have skype account.
can i use multiple instances of same skype id which can handle different incoming calls seperately.
If possible then can you tell me some platform which implements this functionality?
My question is inspired from SIP IVR concept.

Answer (score 0):

One common way to do this would be to use a SIP PABX and IVR (assuming you definitely want it to be SIP based).

Using the SIP PABX you can handle multiple incoming calls to a single SIP address, which is what I think you are asking for, and define logic in the PABX to route those calls whatever way you want - for your example you could send them to an IVR function either within the PABX or in a separate IVR node.

It would probably be a good idea to take a look at some Asterix based IVR solutions - Asterix is probably the best known SIP PABX. The following links should be useful:

- http://www.asterisk.org/get-started/applications/ivr
- [setup an IVR with Asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495271/setup-an-ivr-with-asterisk)
- http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/administration-guide/creating-an-ivr